# TableView header image not showing in iOS 10.2

Tags: ios, uitableview

My Xcode version is 9.0 beta .
 I added a drag-drop tableView header View , Then I added a drag drop imageView onto it . Its working fine on iOS 11 . But image is disappear in iOS 10.2 .

Comment: Can you share some piece of code?

Comment: There is not coding in headerView . just some peaces of  autolayout constraints . And header view is working fine on iOS 11 but Only image view is disappearing from this header View .

I have check some ways like change the position of image or add a UIButton and set button background . But every effort image is not showing . @iRiziya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistakenly the image was in JPG format and not working . I converted it into "PNG" and now working fine .

Answer (score 0):

It will working for me.Please try it for iOS 10.2

Connect the IBOutlet of the table view and header view then write this code in viewDidLoad method.

```
  self.tableView.tableHeaderView = ImageHeaderView
```

Comment: There are several View and one image View on Header View . Header is appear But image is missing . What should I do for this ? @Sanjukta